# Java watching directory is giving me wrong file path for events

Tags: java, directory, java-7

I am using JDK7 "Watching a Directory for Changes" feature. But i found that sometimes it is giving me wrong file path for a particular event on file. Even though the file name is correct. I am facing this problem in **fedora and ubuntu**
Has some one else has faced the same problem.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Download and extract the zip from https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39897681/code/fileOperation.zip for generating files. Please configure it to generate files by reading the README.txt
2. Run the Sample java code by giving a empty source folder and a file[for log purpose] as a input. And wait for some time
3. Run the Main.py from the downloaded content by configuring it so that it generated files and folders.
4. The java program will display the list of files that was present on the disk but not in the list [list generated from the files events received from the watch directory]

*Initally the java output is i.e not events are lost*

Program Output
Pending file count=2398
No files are missed

#

*But we end up missing some events for files or get wrong path after some time*

Pending file count=4552

findFilesPresentOnDiskButNotInList

The files that have been missed are
/data/home/developer/test/folder_0.689628351684/folder_0.0451760705904/folder_0.000447662431096/folder_0.264689686702/folder_0.849536150754/folder_0.216092330336/folder_0.677792564103/folder_0.796242073532

#

Here the folder_0.0451760705904 is created with absolute path /data/home/developer/test/folder_0.689628351684/folder_0.0451760705904 but in the log file it is printing some other path for the folder.

```
import static java.nio.file.LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS;
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE;
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE;
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY;
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.OVERFLOW;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException;
import java.nio.file.ClosedWatchServiceException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.FileVisitResult;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.SimpleFileVisitor;
import java.nio.file.WatchEvent;
import java.nio.file.WatchKey;
import java.nio.file.WatchService;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DirectoryWatcher implements Runnable {
// list of files whose events were received during creation,modification and delete operation
public static List<String> filesList = new ArrayList<String>();
// list of source folder path that we want to monitor
public static List<Path> srcPaths;
private WatchService watcher;
private Map<WatchKey, Path> keys;
private String module = "DirectoryWatcher-";
private boolean trace = false;
FilesetSimpleFileVisitor SFRFileVisitor = new FilesetSimpleFileVisitor();

/**
 * Points to the log file which contains all the information about the
 * events received by directory watcher. Any event that is received by
 * directory watcher is logged into this file with the type of event. eg
 * CREATE <full file path>
 */
public static String LOG_FILE_PATH = null;
public static PrintWriter logFileWriter = null;

public DirectoryWatcher(List<Path> srcPaths) throws IOException {
super();
this.srcPaths = srcPaths;
initWatchService();
registerTopLevelSrcFolder();
new Thread(this).start();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
static <T> WatchEvent<T> cast(WatchEvent<?> event) {
return (WatchEvent<T>) event;
}

private void initWatchService() throws IOException {
watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
keys = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<WatchKey, Path>());
}

private void registerTopLevelSrcFolder() throws IOException {
for (Path dir : srcPaths) {
    try {
    // logger.print(logger.INFO, logger.PFR,
    // "registerTopLevelSrcFolder",
    // "Top level directory to be registered is " + dir);
    System.out.println("Top level directory to be registered is "
        + dir);
    register(dir);
    // doScan(dir);
    // scanAllFilesOnly(dir);
    } catch (AccessDeniedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchFileException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}

/**
 * Exception Register the given directory with the WatchService
 */
private void register(Path dir) throws IOException {
final String subModule = module + "register";

File file = dir == null ? null : dir.toFile();
if (file == null || !file.exists()) {
    return;
}

WatchKey key = dir.register(watcher, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_DELETE,
    ENTRY_MODIFY);
if (trace) {

    Path prev = keys.get(key);
    if (prev == null) {
    } else {
    if (!dir.equals(prev)) {
        addToScannedListOnDirRename(file, true);
    }
    }
}
keys.put(key, dir);
}

/**
 * On rename of a directory it adds all the child folders and files.
 *
 * @param dir
 * @throws PFRScanFailedException
 */
/**
 * On rename of a directory it adds all the child folders and files.
 *
 * @param dir
 * @throws PFRScanFailedException
 */
private void addToScannedListOnDirRename(File dir, boolean rename)
    throws IOException {
// System.out.println("addToScannedListOnDirRename" + dir);
String subModule = module + "addToScannedListOnDirRename";
try {

    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
    if (!rename) {
        try {
        register(Paths.get(dir.getAbsolutePath()));
        } catch (NoSuchFileException e1) {
        // consume.
        }
    }
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    if (files == null) {
        return;
    }
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file == null) {
        continue;
        }
        // doScan(file);
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
        addToScannedListOnDirRename(file, rename);
        }
    }
    }

} finally {

}
}

boolean closed = false;
private String uniqueFSName = "directoryWatcher";

public void close() {
if (closed) {
    return;
}
String subModule = module + "close";
try {
    if (watcher != null) {
    watcher.close();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
} finally {
    freeResources();
}
closed = true;
}

private void freeResources() {
watcher = null;
if (keys != null) {
    keys.clear();
}
// logger.print(logger.VERBOSE, logger.PFR,
// "DirectoryWatcher-freeResources ",
// "end of Directory Watcher. Freeing up resources");
}

private void DirectoryWatcherCore() {

String subModule = module + "DirectoryWatcherCore";
// enable trace after initial registration
trace = true;
for (;;) {
    // wait for key to be signalled
    try {
    WatchKey key = null;
    try {
        key = watcher.take();
    } catch (InterruptedException x) {
        x.printStackTrace();
        return;
    } catch (ClosedWatchServiceException x) {
        x.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    if (key == null) {
        System.out.println("key is nulllllllllllllllllllllll");
    }
    Path dir = keys.get(key);
    // System.out.println("**********" + dir);
    if (dir == null) {
        // logger.print(logger.ERROR, logger.PFR, subModule,
        // "WatchKey not recognized!!");
        continue;
    }

    for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
        final WatchEvent.Kind kind = event.kind();

        if (kind == OVERFLOW) {
        logFileWriter.println("OVERFLOW");
        System.out
            .println("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX----->>>OVERFLOW<<<--------XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

        // triggerFullScan();

        continue;
        }

        // Context for directory entry event is the file name of
        // entry
        WatchEvent<Path> ev = cast(event);
        Path name = ev.context();
        Path child = dir.resolve(name);
        File childPath = child.toFile();
        File parent = dir.toFile();

        // logger.print(logger.VERBOSE2, logger.PFR, subModule,
        // event
        // .kind().name() + " filename "+name+" child " + child +
        // " parent "+dir + " watchable="+key.watchable());

        if (!childPath.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath()
            .equals(parent.getAbsolutePath())) {
        System.out
            .println("ERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR");
        System.out.println(childPath.getParentFile()
            .getAbsoluteFile());
        System.out.println(parent.getAbsolutePath());
        }

        // System.out.println(event.kind().name() +
        // " name "+name+" child " + child + " dir "+dir);
        // if directory is created, and watching recursively, then
        // register it and its sub-directories
        if (kind == ENTRY_CREATE) {
        // System.out.println("created-" + child);
        logFileWriter.println("CREATE:" + child);
        try {
            if (Files.isDirectory(child, NOFOLLOW_LINKS)) {
            try {
                registerAll(child);
                // addToScannedListOnDirRename(child.toFile(),
                // false);
            } catch (NoSuchFileException ex) {
                // logger.print(logger.VERBOSE, logger.PFR,
                // moduleName,
                // "Received ENTRY_CREATE and NoSuchFileException continuing from here "
                // + ex+" for dir "+child);
                continue;
            }

            }
        } catch (AccessDeniedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            triggerFullScan();
            return;
        }
        }

        File file = child.toFile();
        if (kind == ENTRY_CREATE || kind == ENTRY_MODIFY) {
        // System.out.println("created/modify-" + child);
        logFileWriter.println("CREATE/MODIFY: " + child);
        try {
            // logger.print(logger.VERBOSE2, logger.PFR,
            // subModule, "Adding create event = " + fileInfo);

            filesList.add(file.getCanonicalPath());
            if (file.isDirectory()) {

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            triggerFullScan();
            return;
        }
        } else if (kind == ENTRY_DELETE) {
        logFileWriter.println("DELETE: " + child);
        deleteDir(file);
        }
    }

    // reset key and remove from set if directory no longer
    // accessible
    boolean valid = key.reset();
    if (!valid) {
        keys.remove(key);

        // all directories are inaccessible
        if (keys.isEmpty()) {
        break;
        }
    }

    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    triggerFullScan();

    String failureCause = e.getMessage();

    return;
    } catch (Throwable e) {

    triggerFullScan();
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
    }
}
}

private void deleteDir(File file) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private void triggerFullScan() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

/**
 * Register the given directory, and all its sub-directories, with the
 * WatchService.
 *
 * @throws PFRScanFailedException
 */
private void registerAll(final Path start) throws Exception {
// register directory and sub-directories
walkFileTree(start);
}

private void walkFileTree(Path start) throws IOException {
int retryCount = 0;
int maxRetry = 5;

String subModule = module + "walkFileTree";
while (true) {
    try {

    if (start == null) {
        return;
    }

    Files.walkFileTree(start, SFRFileVisitor);
    break;
    } catch (AccessDeniedException adx) {
    retryCount++;
    if (retryCount == maxRetry) {
        throw adx;
    }
    File file = start.toFile();
    if (file == null || !file.exists()) {
        break;
    }

    waitFor(5000);
    continue;
    } catch (IOException iex) {
    retryCount++;
    if (retryCount == maxRetry) {
        throw iex;
    }

    waitFor(5000);
    continue;
    }
}
}

public static void waitFor(int milliseconds) {
try {
    Thread.sleep(milliseconds);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}

/**
 * Process all events for keys queued to the watcher
 */
@Override
public void run() {
Thread.currentThread().setName(uniqueFSName);
try {
    DirectoryWatcherCore();
} finally {
    freeResources();
}
}

class FilesetSimpleFileVisitor extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {

@Override
public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
    throws IOException {
    try {
    // doScan(file);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    // logger.printStackTrace(logger.PFR,
    // "PFRScanFailedException-visitFile", e);
    }
    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
}

@Override
public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir,
    BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
    String subModule = "preVisitDirectory";
    try {
    register(dir);
    // doScan(dir);
    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    } catch (NoSuchFileException e) {
    return FileVisitResult.SKIP_SUBTREE;
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw new IOException(e);
    }
}
}

public void startDirectoryRegisterProcess() throws Exception {
// registering all path
String subModule = "-startDirectoryRegisterProcess-";
// logger.print(logger.INFO, logger.PFR, subModule,
// "Initaited registering process");
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

for (Path dir : srcPaths) {
    // logger.print(logger.INFO, logger.PFR, subModule,
    // "Started registring directory" + dir);
    try {
    // registering sub directories
    File folder = dir.toFile();
    if (folder == null) {
        continue;
    }

    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    if (listOfFiles == null || listOfFiles.length == 0) {
        continue;
    }
    for (File file : listOfFiles) {
        if (file.exists() && file.isDirectory()) {
        try {
            registerAll(Paths.get(file.getCanonicalPath()));
        } catch (NoSuchFileException iox) {
            // consume NoSuchFileException exception
        }

        }
    }

    } catch (AccessDeniedException e) {
    // handleAccessDeniedException(e, true);
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    // handleException(e, true);
    }
}

long registrationTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
}

public static void testWatchDir(List<Path> dirs) throws Exception {

final DirectoryWatcher dw = new DirectoryWatcher(dirs);
Runnable runner = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
        waitFor(10 * 1000);

        System.out.println("Pending file count="
            + filesList.size());

        findFilesPresentOnDiskButNotInList();
        System.out
            .println("----------------------------------");
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }
};
new Thread(runner).start();

dw.startDirectoryRegisterProcess();
}

/**
 * Checks if the file is present on Disk but not on the list which was
 * created by the events that was received by Directory Watcher
 *
 * @throws Exception
 */
public static void findFilesPresentOnDiskButNotInList() throws Exception {
List<String> missedFiles = new ArrayList<String>();

for (Path src : srcPaths) {
    findDiff(src.toFile(), missedFiles);
}
if (missedFiles.size() == 0) {
    System.out.println("No files are missed");
} else {
    System.out.println("findFilesPresentOnDiskButNotInList");
    System.out.println("The files that have been missed are");
    for (String filePath : missedFiles) {
    System.out.println(filePath);
    }
}

System.out.println("###################################");
}

public static void findDiff(File folder, List<String> missedFiles)
    throws Exception {

File[] files = folder.listFiles();
if (files != null && files.length > 0) {
    for (File child : files) {
    if (!filesList.contains(child.getCanonicalPath())) {
        missedFiles.add(child.getCanonicalPath());
    }
    if (child.isDirectory()) {
        findDiff(child, missedFiles);
    }
    }
}
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

System.out.println("started");

List<String> pathNames = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Path> dirPaths = new ArrayList<Path>();
// if two arguments are passed to the main function then
// we assume that the first argument represents the directory where the
// files and folders are getting created. And the second argument is for
// the
// path to the log file.
// else we ask the user to enter input through command line
if (args.length < 2) {
    getUserInput(pathNames);
} else {
    // arg[0] is the folder to be watched
    pathNames.add(args[0]);
    // arg[1] is the log file that has been created
    LOG_FILE_PATH = args[1];
}
// code for log file
System.out.println("The log file is " + LOG_FILE_PATH);
new File(LOG_FILE_PATH).deleteOnExit();
new File(LOG_FILE_PATH).createNewFile();
logFileWriter = new PrintWriter(LOG_FILE_PATH);

for (String path : pathNames) {
    dirPaths.add(Paths.get(path));
}

testWatchDir(dirPaths);

System.out.println("ended");
}

private static void getUserInput(List<String> pathNames) {
System.out
    .println("please enter the path of directory to be watched for events");
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

if (input.hasNext()) {
    pathNames.add(input.nextLine());
}

System.out.println("Please enter the log file path");
if (input.hasNext()) {
    LOG_FILE_PATH = input.nextLine();
}

}

}
```

Comment: That is a lot of code for anyone to read and understand.  Do you have a short, simple, clear example anyone could run and reproduce your issue?

Comment: I strongly recommend *not* to mix `File` and `Path` API. The `File` implementation might have a cache which can become out-of-sync with the other operations. And using `File` and converting back and forth makes no sense anyway. The [methods in class `Files`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) provide all operations `File` offers and will work even if the `Path` cannot be converted to a `File`.

Comment: Do I understand this correctly: your file/folder create/modification simulation runs for some time, but the watcher misses some events? Are there repeated events (create/change/change) on some files? What is the minimum delay between any two events on a single file? Does this agree with the polling frequency of the file system watcher? Is there a local file system notification (on your versions of Ubuntu, etc) or does Java have to fall back on whatever technique must be used? I think you have some ground to cover before you can post a Q like this, with such an awful lot of code!

Comment: @PeterLawrey this code is easy to run. You just need to provide a empyty source folder and a file path to a text file. And then run the script. After few minutes the program itself will tell you what file is present on the disk but not on the list generated by event notification

Comment: @laune i am only creating new files and folders. I am generating new thread for creating files or folder after every few second so that i can stress test it. There are no delete and repeat event. Everytime i create a new file/folder. Java itself provide me with the mechanism of watching the files.

Comment: "Java itself" may or may not rely on a corresponding OS feature.